# Spring - creating multiple ApplicationContext object causes memory leak

Tags: java, spring, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks

I learnt from this comment that creating the object of ApplicationContext multiple times can cause a memory leak.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/12159#issuecomment-453353389

What exactly happens when we create ApplicationContext objects multiple times in program and causing a memory leak?

Comment: Why do you have to create it multiple times ?

Comment: And did you read the rest of the issue, where the bug was fixed?

Comment: It was a bug in the legacy code. We fixed it by making it as a static refernce. We found that issue from heap dump, which shows that DefaultListableBeanFactory object causes the out of memory problem.

Comment: I read the comments in the bug. But being a newbie, I am not able to understand exactly what was the fix. If anybody could please explain it would be of great help.

Comment: When creating an `ApplicationContext` you create instances of all the beans inside it. If you create it again it happens again and again and again until something breaks, which in most cases is memory (or weird transactional issues). You should never have to create an instance of an `ApplicationContext` unless you are writing your own container you need to do it once. When people start writing code like `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` alarm-bells should be ringing...

Comment: However in the hap dump created for our application we didn't see any of the bean objects. Instead I found only ConcurrentHashMap objects defined in DefaultListableBeanFactory class. So I just want to know how creating a new ApplicationContext instance for each request causes out of memory issues. The heapdump looks similar to the one  mentioned here : https://jira.spring.io/secure/attachment/20534/memory%20lekage.jpg

Comment: What about Vaadin? In Vaadin/Spring configuration you create a SpringContext for every user. This is a lot of contextes to keep in memory (we actually observe this in an aplication).